# How do I configure my domain?

Tags: database, wordpress, dns, hosting

I have made a Wordpress website, with the website in a sub-directory called /premier. This hosting space is not mine, but rather the site is hosted on someone else's server.

I would now like to move my website to the root directory of a different domain, that I own.
I am not sure how to configure the DNS settings on my part, and I'm not sure if I simply need to change my Wordpress URL settings, or actually move the files/database.

If anyone knows how to configure this, I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: For domain name changes: [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change). Are you planning to park the new domain or create an addon domain? I'm assuming the server you're using to host will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to remove your web site to another server and another domain (or url).

Then you should look through **wp-config.php** in root of your web site and make it correct for the new server, or re-install yor WP on the new server for true path in wp-config.php and Data Base connections.

Now you should to remove your DB: just export your old one and using any text editor open your *.SQL, use find&replace function to replace your old url by the new one. for example:
http://example.com/sub-folder
replace by
http://newdomain.net

Questions?
Good luck!

Comment: Well the server is remaining the same, with the website in the /premier directory. The domain is changing, yes but the website itself is staying in the same place.

Comment: @user3605075 , if u just remove u'r blog from http://example.com/sub_folder_name than you should to remove only "/sub_folder_name" in all places above (DB, wp-config.php)

Comment: Just to confirm, I have developed my website on a DIFFERENT domain, in the /premier folder. I have recently set it so that the website 'appears' to be in the root folder (whereas the files are still kept in the premier folder).
I have simply trying to configure a new domain to point to this hosting space, without moving the files to a different server.

I am unsure of what my Wordpress settings should be.

Comment: @user3605075, oh! than why did u write that u use WP? This information seems to be not intresting that way. In this case you should connect to u'r hoster company and ask them to connect u'r new domain to u'r old root.

I've understood that u'r site is in the folder (http://example.com), but physicly it's situated in subfolder. So i think that if u'r new domain would redirect user to u'r old domain everithing would be fine. The question is: "is THE DOMAIN set to y'r sub folder, or server configured to work like that?". If domain than just configure new one like old one